# Fisher Information for frequency estimation under non-circular complex Gaussian noise

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance, frequency, fisher-information

Consider a non-circular complex Gaussian noise $v$, which is given as $v = v_r + iv_i$. Here, real and imaginary components are independent and are Normal random variables such as $v_r \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_r,\sigma_r^2)$ and $v_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$.

A frame of $N$ symbols is transmitted over a channel with non-circular additive noise $v$. Assuming ideal timing recovery and frame detection, received symbol after matched filter at $k^{th}$ time is $y_k$.
$$
y_k = (b   + v)x_ke^{i(k\omega +\phi)}
$$
where $b$ is amplitude, $x_k$ is transmitted pilot from PSK modulated alphabet (let's consider BPSK) and $\phi$ is a uniformly distributed phase $(\phi \sim \mathcal{U}(-\pi,\pi])$. Here, $\omega = 2\pi f T$ is normalized unknown frequency (in radians) which is constant over frame length. $T$ is symbol time.
After demodulation, we have
$$
z_k = y_k x_k^* = (b   + v)e^{i(k\omega +\phi)}.
$$
My objective is to find the Fisher information matrix (FIM) for estimation parameters ($\omega,\phi$).
What is the conditional probability of $p(z|\omega,\phi)$, and then how can FIM be found?

Comment: Hi Ahwaq and welcome to DSP.SE! Is this a homework problem or what is the context / use?

Comment: Hi @DanBoschen , thanks. This is not homework. I am working on a research problem.

Comment: frequency and phase are constants, stationary variables once selected at random?

Comment: frequency and initial phase ($\phi$) are constant for one frame and selected randomly from their respective uniform distribution.